# Using Spark-Submit in Docker Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-spark

I am wondering something about PySpark applications. If I container a PySpark program called `my_spark_script.py`, can I just execute it **inside** the Docker container? I mean to ask, is a Docker file like this valid:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster--num-executors 2 my_spark_script.py // <-- ???
```

And I can build it as:

`docker build -t my_docker_image .`

and then run it as

`docker run -d my_docker_image`

I am wondering if this can be run on AWS EC2 or AWS EMR or something else like this? Would it work?

I just dont know how the container `CMD` works in relation to environment like EC2 or EMR. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Elastic Container Service (ECS) is a managed AWS service to run Docker containers. ECS provides the  Fargate launch type, which is a serverless platform with which a container service is run on Docker containers instead of EC2 instances.
To build the source code into a Docker image you can use AWS CodeBuild service, and AWS CodePipeline for Continuous Integration, please check the following example, [here](https://www.infoq.com/articles/aws-codepipeline-deploy-docker/).